# TaskFactory.StartNew behavior

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

What happen if i will use `TaskFactory.StartNew(MyFunc(), new CancellationToken(), TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.Current)` ?

With `TaskScheduler.Current` will it just synchronous execute MyFunc() or use some random thread, or something else?

Comment: Stephen Cleary wrote an excellent post about `StartNew` vs `Run` that covers all the things you need to know about behaviour http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html

Comment: I can't think of a scenario where it ever executes synchronously with the standard task schedulers and synchronization providers.  Never write code that cares about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> With TaskScheduler.Current will it just synchronous execute MyFunc()
>   or use some random thread, or something else?

It depends on the *scope of the execution* and what the value of `Current` is. Though it is *highly unlikely* for this to be executed *synchronously*. Even if the UI synchronization context is used, it will be asynchronously posted using [`BeginInvoke`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.cs,c7dfb662bbd6227d), but it will be posted to the *UI thread*.

About the value of `Current`, [the docs say](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.current(v=vs.110).aspx):

> When not called from within a task, Current will return the Default
>   scheduler.

If you execute this code from another `Task`, where you passed another `TaskScheduler`, than that is what the value of `Current` will be and that is where your delegate will be ran. For example, if the `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext` is captured from the UI thread, you will end up posting this delegate to the UI message loop. Otherwise, it will use `Default`, which is the `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler`, and than your delegate would be invoked on an arbitrary threadpool thread.

Comment: This doesn't answers the question *will it just synchronous execute MyFunc() or use some random thread, or something else?*

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Why would you claim that? The execution of MyFunc is depended on the scope of execution of `StartNew`. That is exactly what the OP asked. I cannot state where it will run unless the OP explicitly showing what context this is being ran in.

Comment: As I'm reading it. OP is also interested in whether it executes synchronously or not. (and the answer is *no*, but that also depends on the `TaskScheduler`). Well, it's convoluted.

Comment: There isn't a *yes/no* answer to that question, because *it depends*. There are cases where this will execute on the UI sync context, in which case you can consider that a synchronous invocation, but there is also a 50% chance this will execute on a threadpool thread.

Comment: Are you sure when it executes in UI context it will be synchronous? I don't think so. It will be asynchronous only.

Comment: Yes, it will be executed asynchronously using `BeginInvoke`. I've edited my answer to reflect that.